# Растянуть <div> на весь экран через padding

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Контент страницы находится в `contanier` со свойствами

```
.wrap > .container {
  padding: 70px 15px 20px;
}
```

Т.е. каждый объект сдвигается на `15px` по бокам. Как растянуть какой-то `div` в `container` под этим свойством на весь экран не обращая внимание на `padding`
Желательно без JS / JQ, но не принципиально

```
<div class='contanier'>
  <div class='need_to'>Растяните меня на всю страницу</div>
</div>
```

Comment: какой див? .container ?

Comment: @Elena Исправил. <div>, находящийся в `contanier`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задать внешние отступы на величину `padding`a: `margin-left: -15px; margin-right: -15px;`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap > .container {
  padding: 70px 15px 20px;
  
}

.need_to {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  background: #ccc; /* для наглядности */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class='need_to'>Растяните меня на всю страницу</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Так годится?

```css
.wrap > .container {
  padding: 70px 15px 20px;
  background: blue;
}

.need_to {
  margin: 0 -15px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div>Не трогайте меня</div>
    <div class='need_to'>Растяните меня на всю страницу</div>
  </div>
</div>
```